# How to speed up the integral in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, performance-tuning, integral-equations, integral-transforms

On the MMA.SE, there have been several question on how to solve equations including integral using `NDSolve`, see [example 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183356/solve-integro-differential-equations), [example 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148541/numerically-solve-an-integro-differential-equation), and [example 3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192123/solving-an-integro-differential-equation-with-mathematica). Many people, like me, have a hard time with this kind of problem. I had raised the last one 5 months ago and obtained a promising answer, since then I have been tried to solve the following equation for a spatially periodic function $u(x,t)$ on $[-L,L]$ with $2L$ periodicity:

$$\partial_t u + u\partial_x u + \partial_x^2 u +\partial_x^4 u
  + a{\rm{int}}[\partial_x^3u] + bu^3  {\rm{int}} [(\partial_x^2u) {\rm{int}}[\partial_x u] ] = 0, \tag{1}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants, and $\rm{int}[f]$ is a spatial integral for a periodic function $f(x,t)$

$${\rm{int}}[f](x,t)=\frac{1}{2L}\mathrm{PV}\int_{-L}^L f(x^\prime,t)\cot\left[\frac{\pi(x-x^\prime)}{2L}\right]\:\mathrm{d}x^\prime, \tag{2} $$

which should be understood in the sense of principal value (PV) since there is a singularity at $x=x^\prime$.

This equation is subjected to periodic boundary conditions and an initial condition. In my real problem, it has several $\rm{int}$ terms and its nest, like ${\rm{int}}[(\partial_x^2u) \rm{int}[\cdots] ]$, which will be solved over a large domain and a long time, say, $L=30$ and $t_\text{max}=200$ (much larger than those in my [original post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192123/solving-an-integro-differential-equation-with-mathematica)). I tried [Michael's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192736/55777) but found that even for that simplified version of Eq.(1) (without the last nested term)
the code is extremely slow, though it works. Actually, I also posted [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192722/55777) based on the finite difference method, but the accuracy of my code is not as good as Michael's. (That is why I didn't accept any answer.) Also, the problem has stiffness due to the high-order derivatives and nonlinear terms. So I have added some `Method` options to `NDSolve` ProcessEquations.

**The Mathematica code**

```
L = 30; tmax = 30; a = 1; b = 1/100; c = 1/(2 L); e = 1/10; nGrid = 91;
ic[x_] = e*Cos[\[Pi]*x/L];

sys = {D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
 D[u[x, t], {x, 4}] + a*int[D[u[x, t], {x, 3}], x, t] + 
 b*u[x, t]^3*intnest[D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]*int[D[u[x, t], x], x, t], x, t] == 0, u[-L, t] == u[L, t], u[x, 0] == ic[x]};

periodize[data_] := Append[data, {N@L, data[[1, 2]]}];(*for periodic interpolation*)

Block[{int, intnest},
  (* IC fools ProcessEquations to consider int[] as a good num.fn.*)
  int[uppp_, x_?NumericQ, t_ /; t == 0] := (cnt++;
    c*NIntegrate[D[ic[xp], {xp, 3}]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L}, 
    Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> {"PrincipalValue", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}},
      PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]);
  int[uppp_?VectorQ, xv_?VectorQ, t_?NumericQ] := Function[x, cnt++;
     c*NIntegrate[Interpolation[periodize@Transpose@{xv, uppp}, xp, 
         PeriodicInterpolation -> True]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L},
       Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> {"PrincipalValue", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}},
       PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]] /@xv;
  intnest[upp_, x_?NumericQ, t_ /; t == 0] := (cnt2++;
    c*NIntegrate[D[ic[xp], {xp, 2}]*int[D[ic[xp], xp], x, t]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L}, 
      Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> {"PrincipalValue", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}},
      PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]);
  intnest[upp_?VectorQ, xv_?VectorQ, t_?NumericQ] := Function[x, cnt2++;
     c*NIntegrate[Interpolation[periodize@Transpose@{xv, upp}, xp, 
         PeriodicInterpolation -> True]*Cot[\[Pi] (x - xp)/(2*L)], {xp, x - L, x, x + L},
       Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", Method -> {"PrincipalValue", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}},
       PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 10]] /@xv;
  (*monitor while integrating pde*)
  Clear[foo];
  cnt = 0; cnt2 = 0;
  PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{foo, cnt, cnt2, Clock[Infinity]};
  (*broken down NDSolve call*)
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{MapThread},
   {state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[sys, u, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax},
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> nGrid, "MaxPoints" -> nGrid, "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"},
       Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> Automatic}},
      AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
     MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], StepMonitor :> (foo = t)];
   Unprotect[MapThread];
   MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int] := f @@ data;
   Protect[MapThread];
   NDSolve`Iterate[state, {0, tmax}];
   sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

**My problem**

As mentioned above, the code is very slow. An estimation: $>2$ hrs may be required to obtain convergence with `tmax = 1`. Btw, the "slwcon" and "ncvb" warning could be ignored (see Michael's comments following his answer there). Is there any approach that would help speed up the code? Thank you very much.

**Some ideas**

As suggested by Henrik Schumacher,  the combination of `NIntegrate` and `Interpolation` limits the speed of this code. Maybe it could be better to use a fixed quadrature rule and implement the integration with `ListConvolve`. But I need help with implementing this idea in my problem, so I bring this problem here in the hope that someone could help.

I am thinking that can we divide the interval into a uniform grid with $2M$($=\rm{nGrid}-1$) mesh points defined by $x_m=(m-M)h$, where $h=L/M$. Please see also [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192722/55777) to a similar problem. Then the integral term (2) could be evaluate at the midpoints $x_{i+1/2}=(x_i+x_{i+1})/2$, for $i=0,1,\ldots,2M-1$, (note the periodicity demands $u_0=u_{2M}$) using a certain integration rule, e.g., trapezoidal rule, with $x_i$ as integration nodes. In this way,
**the principal value integral could be efficiently computed, as if it were simply an ordinary integral.**

Comment: This PDE is parabolic of order 5. Those _are_ hard (and slow) to integrate, even with implicit methods. With the integral term: _Mathematica_ does not know how to handle it implicitly. Moreover, the combination of `NIntegrate` and `Interpolation` is bound to be very slow. Maybe it s better to find a suitable fixed quadrature rule and implement it by hand and compute the integral by `ListConvolve`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher could you show an example by computing the integral by `ListConvolve` using, say, trapezoidal integration or provide a relevant link? Thank you very much!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Is it possible to compile the code (partially) in order to speed up the computation?

Comment: No, integration of `Integration` does not help.

Comment: Cimpilation of `Integrate` is useluess in_any_ case unless the integral can be computed analytically.

Comment: @user55777 Greatly slows down the code option `"DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"`. In this problem it will be enough to take `"DifferenceOrder" -> 2` and put `nGrid = 41;`. Then the calculation takes about a minute.

Comment: @user55777 OK!  I will try to build a solution using the colocation method. But there is a nonlinearity $u^5$ there. We need to think about how to get around this problem.

Comment: @user55777 We have $bu^3L_1uL_2u$,and  it's like $u^5$ for the colocation method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96441/discussion-between-user55777-and-alex-trounev).

Comment: @AlexTrounev [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21170/55777) appears to be helpful? Or can we just treat the first five terms with collocation  method, and evaluate the last term with Michael’s ‘int[]’ function?

Comment: @user55777 I am working on the implementation of the method. As soon as the results appear, I will immediately publish.

Comment: @user55777 Unfortunately, the solution of this problem using the colocation method requires 100 times more time than the iteration method, since there is no effective expression of the integrals.

Comment: @AlexTrounev the integral term can be evaluated as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/350/55777).

Comment: @user55777  You sent me a note, asking that I look at this post.  What advice are you seeking from me?  Best wishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to solve this problem using the decomposition of the solution in a Fourier series. Then it is possible to replace the integrals with the coefficients of the Fourier series using the following obvious property
 $$\frac {1}{2\pi}\int _{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-inx'}\cot((x-x')/2)dx'=ie^{-inx}(1+ \mbox{sign}(n))  $$ It is exactly equal to `FourierCoefficient[Cot[(x - xp)/2], xp, n]`
The result is a fairly simple code. But the calculation does not coincide with that obtained using the author's code. It means that we have to write another third code to test these two. For ease of use of Fourier series, we convert the coordinate and time according to `x->k0 x, t->k0 t`, `k0=Pi/L`.

```
L = 30; tmax = 30; a = 1; b = 1/100; c = 1/(2 L); e = 1/10; nn = 10; k0 = Pi/L; tm = tmax*k0;
a1 = a/k0;
uf[x_, t_] := Sum[f[k][t] Exp[I k x], {k, -nn, nn}]
eq = Table[
   f[m]'[t] + 
     I Sum[ If[Abs[m - k] <= nn, f[m - k][t], 0] k f[k][t], {k, -nn, 
        nn, 1}] - k0*m^2 f[m][t] + k0^3 m^4 f[m][t] - 
     a k0^2 (I m)^3 I (1 - Sign[m]) f[m][t] + 
     b k0^2 Sum[
       If[Abs[m - k - s1 - s2 - s3] <= nn, 
        f[s1][t] f[s2][t] f[s3][t] f[k][t] f[m - k - s1 - s2 - s3][
          t] I (1 - Sign[k]) I (1 - Sign[m - k - s1 - s2 - s3]), 
        0], {s1, -nn, nn}, {s2, -nn, nn}, {s3, -nn, nn}, {k, -nn, 
        nn}] == 0, {m, -nn, nn, 1}];

ic = Table[
   f[m][0] == 
    e (KroneckerDelta[m, 1] + KroneckerDelta[m, -1])/2, {m, -nn, nn, 
    1}];
var = Table[f[i], {i, -nn, nn, 1}]; 
 soli = NDSolve[{eq, ic}, var, {t, 0, tm}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Here is a comparison with the calculation using code @user55777 (left), Fourier (top right) and both codes at time t = 30 (bottom left). The bottom right shows the calculation without integrals (green curve) and with integrals (red curve) by the Fourier method.

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Re[uf[x, t] /. soli]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, tm}, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: @user55777 (1) `uf[x,t]` used in `Plot3D[Evaluate[Re[uf[x, t] /. soli]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, tm}, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]`; (2)  just call `FourierCoefficient[Cot[(x - xp)/2], xp, n]`

Comment: (1) In that case, @Alex Trounev why you used `(1 - Sign[n])` instead of `(1 + Sign[n])` in the code? (2) if the computation domain in your code is `[-\pi,\pi]` how did you plot for `[-30,30]`?

Comment: @user55777 (1) This is due to the definition of the function `uf[x_, t_] := Sum[f[n][t] Exp[I n x], {n, -nn, nn}]`, thus, it is necessary to make a replacement `n->-n` to satisfy the definition `FourierCoefficient[Cot[(x - xp)/2], xp, n]`. (2) just use `Plot[{Re[uf[Pi x/L, tm] /. soli], u[x, tmax] /. sol}, {x, -L, L}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Fourier", " @user55777"}]`.

Comment: @user55777 (1) $u^2u_x$=`I Sum[ If[Abs[m - k1 - k2] <= nn, f[k1][t] f[k2][t] (m - k1 - k2) f[m - k1 - k2][t],0], {k1, -nn, nn, 1}, {k2, -nn, nn, 1}]`; (2) $u^5(u_x)^2$=`- Sum[ If[Abs[m - k1 - k2-k3-k4-k5-k6] <= nn, f[k1][t] f[k2][t] f[k3][t] f[k4][t] f[k5][t] f[k6][t] k6 (m - k1 - k2-k3-k4-k5-k6) f[m - k1 - k2-k3-k4-k5-k6][t],0], {k1, -nn, nn, 1}, {k2, -nn, nn, 1}, {k3, -nn, nn, 1}, {k4, -nn, nn, 1}, {k5, -nn, nn, 1}, {k6, -nn, nn, 1}]`

Comment: @user55777 Yes, it is right.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. Response to your 2nd reply @Alex Trounev, I have trouble in understanding the replace n->-n. If it is the case, why you have f[m] instead of f[-m] in the 5th term? Could u criticize the following: $a{\rm{int}}[\partial_x^3 u]=a{\rm{int}}[({\rm{i}}m)^3f[m][t]e^{{\rm{i}}mx}]=a\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}({\rm{i}}m)^3f[m][t]e^{{\rm{i}}mx^{\prime}}\cot((x-x^{\prime})/2)dx^{\prime}$ with $m\rightarrow-m$, becomes $a\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(-im)^3f[-m][t]e^{-{\rm{i}}mx^{\prime}}\cot((x-x^{\prime})/2)dx^{\prime}=-a{\rm{i}}e^{-{\rm{i}}mx}(1+sgn(m))(im)^3f[-m][t]$

Comment: @user55777 So it is also possible, the result will be the same. As an alternative, we can change the sign `x``

Comment: Thanks @Alex Trounev, could you show your derivation of $a{\rm{int}}[\partial_x^3u]$. I hope to compare ours for a better understanding.

Comment: Dear@Alex Trounev, I studied Fourier transform method recently and learned that in computing derivative using, e.g. $u_x\vert_{x_j}=\sum_{n=-N/2}^{n=N/2-1}{\rm{i}}k_n\hat{u}(k_n)\exp({\rm{i}}k_n x_j)$, for real $u(x)$, the Fourier coefficient of the derivative for $n=-N/2$ should be set to zero to avoid the calculation of a "noisy derivative". But in your method (1) we did see you set it to zero; (2) you used mode from $-N/2$ to $N/2$ instead of $N/2-1$. I guess those are the origins of the difference.

Comment: @user55777 I will try to write a third code to test these two.

Comment: Thank you@Alex Trounev, btw in the convention employed by the FT command of MMA, the Fourier transform has $\rm{i}$ in the exponent instead of $-\rm{i}$ and vice versa for the inversion formula. Different choices of conventions can be specified using `FourierParameter`, with which your first identity and the definition of `uf[x_, t_]` can be consistent without the replacement of $n\rightarrow-n$. Please see the details under `FourierTransform` for example.

Comment: `nGrid = 21;` and `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "MinPoints" -> nGrid, "MaxPoints" -> nGrid, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 
     2}}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, MaxSteps \
-> 10^6`